# Does Application_Start block all incoming requests

Tags: asp.net, application-start

I have some code that initializes a static singleton class, which is needed by all requests. Therefore I thought I could add it to global.asax Application_Start. Can I be 100% sure that all requests will block while Application_Start is loading to guarantee that all the requests will have access to it?

Thanks a lot
Jeeji

Answer (score 15):

Short answer: yes.

Application_Start:

> Called when the first resource (such
>   as a page) in an ASP.NET application
>   is requested. The Application_Start
>   method is called only one time during
>   the life cycle of an application. You
>   can use this method to perform startup
>   tasks such as loading data into the
>   cache and initializing static values.
>
> You should set only static data during
>   application start. Do not set any
>   instance data because it will be
>   available only to the first instance
>   of the HttpApplication class that is
>   created.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx